# hardware/ril-caf/rild/rild.c:60: error: undefined reference to 'joinRpcThreadpool'

Tags: c

I'm new and have a question that I can't answer.
I'm playing a little bit with LineageOS 15 to build a rom for my device. (Lineage 14.1 is successfully built by me...)
So I downloaded the sources for that target as I usually did before.
But I'm running into some errors. One of these is this one.
The function joinRpcThreadpool() is called like this:

```
void rilc_thread_pool() {
    joinRpcThreadpool();
}
```

I know how to declare and implement an unknown function, but I can't find how this unknown function is working and how it looks like.

Comment: Search the header files for the function declaration using something like `grep`.  It could be that the inclusion is dependant on some preprocessor macros.  Or it could be that you are not including all the source code you need.  BTW, a quick Google (other search engines are available) gave this:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/libhidl/+/master/transport/include/hidl/HidlTransportSupport.h  - this looks like C++, not C.

Comment: I've searched the whole source path for a file containing the string "joinRpcThreadpool". I've found several calls to this function but nothing about this function itself. A search in the internet was not helpful. It seems that this function is not described as usual. Maybe it depends on a macro. I'm searching and testing a bit more...

Comment: I think I've found a way to solve this problem: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/b6a6283ce48af09bf833f0622988d464ecc5104c But this looks not easy. I'll give it a try... ;-) And, yes, it looks like c++, not c ...